# Resin printers: What effect does altering the lift distance on a Resin printer have, and what are the consequences of getting it wrong?

Tags: slicing, sla

Slicing software for resin printers: Chitubox, for example, has a setting labelled "Lift Distance", which as far as I can tell determines how far build plate is lifted in between layers.

A layer is printer, the build plate is moved a set distance upwards, and is then moved back down again until the lowest layer is just above the FEP, ready for the next layer to be exposed.

In Chitubox this defaults to 7mm.

What effect does increasing this beyond 7mm have, will it simply increase the total print time or have any other effects.

Will reducing it below 7mm have any effects, other than decreasing the total print time?

If the distance is set too low, will it mean that new resin cannot flow properly into the gap under the build plate, or are there other potential consequences?

Comment: Your username made me smile.  Thank you... I needed that. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Print time

Raising the bed takes time. In fact, it is possibly more time spent in moving the bed than curing the layers.

## Caveat emptor!

You can reduce the lift height, but you might suffer:

Lifting too little means, that you might not move enough to separate from the FEP film fully - the film is a somewhat stretchy film and you need to raise enough to come free fully to get clean layers, resulting in deformed or missing areas or even just a solid plate that stays at the bottom and separates from the printed.

High viscosity resin not properly flowing in might also be a problem, but of lesser importance generally.